# Print a gridview in multiple pages

Tags: asp.net

I have  a gridview with 30 columns and I need to print the whole gridview.

I tried in some way but its resulting in good thing. I need to print the gridview

in two or three pages. The gridview having paging also in it.

How can I do this?

I need serial number for each row for all the pages of the gridview in the print part.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Quick response,

I ahve already have some code to print the gridview,

Its not the problem.

When my gridview having more columns That time I need to print the gridview

into many pages, like for the first page 1-10 columns

for the second page 11-20 columns,

But I need to click only once the print button in the print dialog box.